# Using args [0] in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class argu {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int number = Integer.parseInt(args [0]);
    int x = number % 2;

    if (x == 0) {
        System.out.println("It is even");

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("It is not even");
    }
        }
    }
```

I have been trying to code this program to make an user enter a number, (that is the args [0] for), however, it sends this error.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at argu.main(argu.java:7)

The fix I made was

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class argu {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    int number = scan.nextInt();
    int x = number % 2;

    if (x == 0) {
        System.out.println("It is even");

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("It is not even");
    }
        }
    }
```

I want to know if there is a way to user args [0] instead of the Scanner method. Keep in mind, I am a beginner, so I am sorry some of the stuff is wrong

My other question is to help me analyze the method 
Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

scan is the variable?
Scanner is the method?
I am confused with variables, parameters, and methods. If you could help me differentiate one from the other.

Thank you.

Comment: "I want to know if there is a way to user args [0] instead of the Scanner method" yes there is, but I am not sure if you really want to. Do you know what `args` represents/stores?

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse to add an argument to the program you have to add a *run configuration* with that argument.

That's in the `Run` -> `Run Configurations...` -> pick your configuration (probably "main" or "argu") -> `Arguments` (tab) -> add arguments in `Program Arguments` (top text field, Name your configuration something meaningful).

Now use this configuration to run the program. You can have many different configurations obviously.

[image: Image from the relevant dialog]

Answer (score 1):

`args[0]` indicates the arguments when used to start up the program - this is done using commands.

Say you ran this command through cmd or the terminal:

```
java -jar myjar.jar 5
```

The value of `args[0]` would be 5, because 5 in the command is an argument. The argument is passed to `args[]`. Adding another argument would go to args[1]:

```
java -jar myjar.jar 5 10
```

`args[1]` would equal 10.

See @Ruets answer for details on how to use arguments in Eclipse.

You get your error because args[0] is not existent - the command would look more something like this:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```